# "Changes to how" or "changes in how"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions, collocation

I have the following sentence:

> Since that experience, I have made changes *to how* I address all of my courses.

Should I use "to how" or "in how" for any grammatical reason(s), or is it simply a matter of personal preference?

Comment: They're both fine, and it would be stretching a point to claim any *semantic* distinction. But [***in** is much more common*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+change+in+how%2Ca+change+to+how&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20change%20in%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20change%20to%20how%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thanks for providing a mathematically proven answer to my english question!  Great response!

Comment: The embedded question complement clause _how I address all of my courses_ is, as usual, acting as a noun phrase, and therefore it is the object of _to_. It can be the object of any preposition, like any noun phrase. The preposition _to_ itself is governed by the noun _changes_, and I take the question to be whether _in_ can be used in the same place. The answer is that it can. _We detected a change in the temperature_ is normal, but ***to** the temperature* means somebody's been fooling with the thermostat. _To_ seems more at home with active causation of change, _in_ with inchoative.

Comment: @Lawson: I've no knowledge either way, but I'm guessing you're a native speaker, so once you see John's distinction there, you instantly recognise the truth of it. Nevertheless, I think questions like this are more suitable on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think that the phrase "I have made changes to/in how I address all of my courses" sounds stiff and awkward, in part because it doesn't settle on a consistent tone. If you want to sound like a serious student, you might say "I have altered my approach to all of my courses." If you want to sound down-to-earth, you might say "I have changed the way I deal with all my courses." But the diction used in the original sentence seems to me to be both inconsistent and unnatural, regardless of whether you choose _to_ or _in_ to lead the way to _how_.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it's a moot point now, the essay this sentence was part of succeeded in getting me admitted to my college of choice!

Comment: @Venoda Please allow ELU subscribers to judge what is moot and what remains of value. ELU is intended for all who wish to and adhere to the rules to benefit from.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler stated in the comments:

> The embedded question complement clause *how I address all of my courses* is, as usual, acting as a noun phrase, and therefore it is the object of to. It can be the object of any preposition, like any noun phrase. The preposition *to* itself is governed by the noun changes, and I take the question to be whether *in* can be used in the same place. The answer is that it can. We detected a change in the temperature is normal, but to the temperature means somebody's been fooling with the thermostat. *To* seems more at home with active causation of change, *in* with inchoative. [– John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)

Answer (score 0):

There's not much difference in meaning.
Maybe 'to how' is more pro-active and 'in how' is less so.
'to' sounds more immediate and is more usual.
'in' sounds (subtlely) like a more long term thing.
I'd go for 'to how'.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. Thank you for trying to help out another user by answering their question. Your answer could be made more useful, though, by adding some reasons other than your opinion about the phrases, preferably backed up by research or references.